# How can I make a fresh install of 1.9 keeping my data?

Tags: magento-1.9, install, backup

I've been using Magento for a while, but somehow I screwed something. Some functions aren't working well (for example, the "Flush CSS/Javascript" buttons are gone, the shipping cost isn't shown on the Checkout Review, and some other weird issues.

I would like to make a fresh install, only keeping my template files, and everything else clean, but keeping my data. As far as I know, this is not possible only with Magento export options (only products and customers). I have some extensions with data I would like to keep and of course the categories and main configs.

Is there a way to do this without having to manually add the new data?

Answer (score 1):

What I would suggest here is to create a fresh install of the code base and then during the install process use the currently used database.

Then you can start to build ontop of what should be a "stable" code base and add any extensions that you are looking for.

To do this what you could simply do is a mysqldump and then import into a new database.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it will take a great amount of time to find all the errors (chances are you might miss out some errors, maybe?)

Maybe you can try this (What I will do, normally):

Check your CSS files to look for certain codes (maybe you accidentally comment it out or delete a portion of it)

That said, you may try the solution below if the above fails:

1. Install a fresh Magento 1.9
2. Install all necessary extensions
3. Backup necessary tables via PhpMyAdmin (screwed version)
4. Import to new installation

Comment: thanks for your answer. I ended un installing a fresh one but over the old DB. Then installed extensions and is working fine (not perfect, but at least usable).

Comment: Great, that is good to hear. :)